# How to run batch transactions in neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j, batch-processing

We are working on a recommendation engine use case at the production level.

We had a use case to fetch products sorted based on geography(nearest first), we thought to make use of spatial functions like distance and point to sort them.
For that, we need latitude and longitude properties in Product nodes, which we don’t have yet, but we have a postal address, so we figured, we’ll make use of call apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce, fetch, and set latitude and longitude properties in all the Product nodes.

Well, a bit of problem is it’s becoming an expensive operation, we have around 5000 product nodes, it’s taking an average 1000 ms to update each node, by that calculation, on a single core, it’d take around 90 min to update all the nodes. We are really curious to know if there’s a smarter way to handle the transaction in chunks(maybe, updating 500 products in one tx then, next 500…  and so on). We thought, apoc.periodic.iterate is a way to go but we are looking for suggestions on how do we solve this problem efficiently?

P.S - When we tried out a few apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce calls to a couple of products with the postal address we have in our db, we saw a couple of calls returned no result, what could be the possible reasons for this? (maybe, we don’t have standardized postal addresses for such products? if so how shall we address the problem, shall we make use of google geocode API for those products or there are other smarter ways embedded in neo4j)

Our query below for reference:

CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (p:Product) return p",
"CALL apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce(p.postal_address) YIELD location SET p.latitude=location.latitude, p.longitude=location.longitude",
{batchSize:500, iterateList:true, parallel:true}
)

Answer (score 1):

It's due to throttle of apoc.spatial.geocodeOnce API calls. There's a rate-limiter on the number of requests you can make to the server.

You can buy google geocode API Key, configure inside **apoc.conf** file like,

```
apoc.spatial.geocode.provider=google
apoc.spatial.geocode.google.throttle=1
apoc.spatial.geocode.google.key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Note - throttle here, is in mSec